# Does geospatial server software exist which can support dynamically generated imagery as a WMS?

Tags: wms, netcdf, imagery, multi-band, rgb

Here's the situation:

- **Input:**

  - A bunch of data (NetCDF) that contains seperate variables/arrays for R/G/B channels.
- **Desired output:**

  - Web service (e.g. WMS) that can serve simulated true-color imagery derived from input channels.
- **Limitations:**

  - I can't duplicate the data (e.g. pre-process and have a collection of TIFFs to read), it needs to be computed and served on-the-fly as there is a lot of data and any duplication is out of scope.
  - Need to apply some color enhancements so solution needs to support some arbitrary middleware (preferably Python) to adjust the values.

I *could* do this a number of bespoke ways but an OGC solution such as WMS would be much preferred if possible.

I know GeoServer supports a number of extensions for reading data from various databases, I wonder if there anything that supports executing an arbitrary script to return the data?

Answer (score 2):

[GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) provides rendering transformations that can do exactly this. The [manual contains an example](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#running-map-algebra-on-the-fly-using-jiffle) using [Jiffle](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/wiki/Jiffle---language-summary) that calculates NDVI on the fly from multiband Sentinel data.

```
    <Transformation>
      <ogc:Function name="ras:Jiffle">
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>coverage</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
          <ogc:Literal>script</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>
            nir = src[7];
            vir = src[3];
            dest = (nir - vir) / (nir + vir);
          </ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
    </Transformation>
```

You could ultimately write your own processing plugin functions in [Java](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/programming-guide/wps-services/implementing.html) or (more difficult) in [Python](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/scripting/py/index.html) to implement custom code.